# Questions with "did" in English

Tags: questions

Is the sentence below correct?

> He sent you here, did he?

I have learned that in English the first form of the verb is used with ***did***.

> Did he send you?

Even I feel the sentence below is correct:

> He has sent you here, has he?

Answer (score 1):

> He sent you here, did he?

and

> Did he send you?

and

> He has sent you here, has he?

are all perfect English.

If sentence 2 ended with "here" it would mean the same as sentence 1.

sentence 1 is a little more idiomatic than sentence 2, which is a little abrupt. They are both in the Past tense.

BUT sentence 3 is in the Present Perfect tense.

Comment: Both sentences has same meaning?. Please explain in context

Comment: @user4084 Sorry. I've edited my answer. Does it help? I don't understand what else you want to know.

Comment: Thanks , But Did with sent (past tense) is not english. Can u help me some other example?. He changed this , did he ?

Comment: You are right. "Did you sent" is not correct English. Some other examples:  (1) She gave you it, did she? Did she give you it? She has given you it, has she? (2)You ate it, did you? Did you eat it? You've eaten it, haven't you? (3)They saw it, didn't they? Did they see it? They've seen it, haven't they?  [Is that enough?]

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? 1 and 3 both sound poorly constructed to my ear. Please can you add some references to your answer?

Comment: I agree with @Bee. 1 and 3 sound bad to my ear too...

Comment: They are all correct.  You can also say **”He sent you here, *didn’t* he?”**, for a slightly different nuance (meaning).

Comment: #1 is unusual but correct. It can be used to suggest the speaker is **questioning** the statement.  “How did you find this place?” “He sent me here.” “He sent you here, did he?”  In conversational English you might hear: “***Oh***, he sent you here, did he?”